# Entity Framework Core issue after windows server patching

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a .NET Core 3.1/5 application deployed to a Windows 2022 server in Azure.

Recently after server patching, later version of .NET Core get installed, ASP.NET Core 6.0.21 and 7.0.10 and .NET runtime for both versions. Then my web application is broken.

The application still can be load, but breaks when I try to do this:

```
createRequestList = allRequests.Select(ar => new CreateRequestViewModel
{
    RequestId = ar.RequestId,
    CorporationName = ar.Corporation.CorporationName,
    CreationDate = ar.CreationDate
}).ToList();
```

I have `allRequests` and `createRequestList` defined like this:

```
var allRequests = Enumerable.Empty<Request>().AsQueryable();
allRequests = (from r in _context.Request
               where (r.Status != "Closed")
               select r).AsQueryable(); 
var createRequestList = new List<CreateRequestViewModel>();
```

All I got is an HTTP 500 error and the message I wrote into event log shows it stopped at where the select query is.

This only happens in production server, I couldn't reproduce it in my local machine.

The ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework Core package version are at 5.0.5 in NuGet.

Apart from updating my application to a later version like .NET 6 or 7, is restoring the server from backup the only option?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it shows "it stopped at where the select query is" it must show the Exception and Stack Trace, post that.

Comment: @mxmissile Thanks. it doesn't show anything. just some simple text saying "This page isn't working right now" with HTTP ERROR 500, a blank page. I commented out my error handling in Startup.cs app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error/Error"); and app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/Error/StatusCode/{0}"); Did I miss anything?

Comment: ar. got it, just force it to run in Development environment.

Comment: Your server implementation should have exception catching and handling to log exceptions with their callstacks. Web applications by default will, and should just return 500 server errors to the browser to avoid giving useful information to would-be attackers. As for the upgrade issue, .Net Core is not like .Net Framework in terms of support and backwards compatibility, They expect you as a developer to be keeping your projects up-to-date and supported as Core versions are only supported for 18-36 months.